# How to show that proper direct image is left adjoint to inverse image?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, adjoint-functors

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper map of schemes. How do I show that $f^* \vdash f_!$? That is, how do I show that proper direct image is left adjoint to inverse image?

Somewhere I need to use that $f$ is separated, i.e. $X \rightarrow X \times_Y X $ is closed, and that it is universally closed, i.e. that $X \times_Y Z \rightarrow Z$ is closed, and probably (but maybe not?) that it is of finite type. It seems like the proof would be long, so maybe a reference would be nice.

---

Evidently, one is supposed to show that $f_*$ has a right adjoint when $f$ is proper, and that the right adjoint is $f^*$? Maybe someone can outline the steps for me.

---

I messed up -- [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+context) is what should be the case. I would instead like a proof that $f_! $ is left adjoint to $f^!$.

Comment: Are you talking about coherent sheaves or étale sheaves or something else ? Can you give a reference for this statement (because, as stated I don't think it is true...)

Comment: quasicoherent sheaves. here’s the closest thing I can find to a reference: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3312/when-does-direct-image-with-proper-support-have-a-right-adjoint

Comment: This is the left adjoint part with bothers me. We indeed have  $f_!=f_*$ so that $f_!$ is right adjoint to $f^*$ when $f$ is proper. But for instance, for a closed immersion (which is proper) $f^*$ does not have a left adjoint since it is not left exact.

Comment: Oh wait, you're right. I meant that. I would be quite grateful if you could outline the proof in enough detail for me to figure this out.

Comment: I see now -- what I want a proof of is that $f_!$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: I can definitely see that $f_!$ and $f_*$ coincide when $f$ is proper, but not that $f_!$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: Actually $f_!$ does not always have a right adjoint, even if $f$ is proper. The adjoint exists only in the derived setting. And be careful because if $f$ is not proper, $f_!$ usually does not preserve quasi-coherence. I will not write the proof here, because they are not so easy and not so short, and also because you can easily find it in the literature (and there are lots of references in the links you provided). But you can ask a question on the website if there are parts of the proof that you don't understand.

Comment: Ok - I see. Thanks very much for your help. Also, I must apologize if my error was annoying.